# SSRS table to fetch all columns at once

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a problem with SSRS reporting.

If I have a table in SQL which is having 60 column and I want to display  all 60 column in reports. I have to drag and drop all 60 columns in my table which is not good. Is there a way where we can put all 60 columns in the reports directly.

If we drag and drop table from toolbox in SSRS, it is by default a 3 column and 2 rows so if I have another 57 rows I have to increase the column 1 by 1 and then select a column which is such a pain.

Is there a way we can do it all at once?

[image: SSRS]

Comment: You can just drag a column.

Comment: I know I can drag a column and it will increase automatically, but If i have 100 columns I have to drag and drop 100 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the easiest way to get 60 (or 100) columns on a report is to run through the report wizard and have that build the report for you, making sure to select all of the columns at the appropriate step.

Then, you can take the table that the wizard builds and move it to another report, or style the new report to meet your needs.

I have often wished I could just drag the dataset to the report body, and whammo -> instant table. Alas, no silver bullet there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly. In this case, Report wizard is the solution for OP.